# Advertising as DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a DHCP and DNS server running from BIND on CentOS 7.  Clients (Windows and Linux) automatically DHCP to the CentOS server and everything works hunky-dory.  However, the only way DNS works is if I set the DNS server manually on Windows and Linux clients.  Is there a way to broadcast as a DNS server? Or should I be setting my DNS server on my router (pfSense)?

Answer (score 2):

This can be served through DHCP options and depends on the DHCP server you are using. Assuming that you use `isc-dhcpd` the required option in the config would be `option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.11`.

As this option is a standard dhcp option the clients should set the DNS servers as specified.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS server should set as a scope option on your DHCP server.
If you're using BIND I believe it can be set in the DHCP server configuration:

option domain-name-servers [CentOS7machineIP];

Then when your windows/linux clients grab an address, they will also get the DNS server settings.

Personally, if I had a PFSense on the same network I would be running DHCP and DNS from that instead.

Cheers

Luke